# How to set Python 3.6 as default for Zappa?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, virtualenv

I'm trying to use Zappa (and AWS Lambda) in a virtual environment. I've already installed Zappa, but when I try running `zappa init` I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: This version of Python (3.5) is not supported!
Zappa (and AWS Lambda) support the following versions of Python: ['2.7', '3.6']
```

I've already installed Python 3.6, but Python 3.5 goes by default when I start a new virtual env. What should I do?

Comment: It's a problem with your local environment not Zappa. What do you get when you do `python -V`?

Comment: You need to use the other python binary to create your virtualenv

Answer (score 1):

Refering to the [python-guide on virtualenv](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/), you can create a virtualenv using the python executable of your choice like this:

```
$ virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 my_project
```

Now, the path of the python executable should point to your installed Python3.6 executable. Probably `/usr/bin/python3.6`.

If `$ python -V` gives you the correct version (3.6), then you can also find the path using `$ which python`.

Comment: In other words, use (eg) `virtualenv -p python3.6 env`, then install your packages (including Zappa) and you'll be running in Python 3.6.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem I am using python3.5, to make it works I have not change the python version for my env but inside env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/zappa/**init**.py

I have added (3, 5) in between

SUPPORTED_VERSIONS = [(2, 7), (3, 5), (3, 6)]

And it works

Comment: ./zappa/__init__.py